# Book about planet with two semi intelligent species "foxes" and "hounds"

Tags: story-identification, books

I read this about 2010 the book features a human colonized planet with two semi intelligent species. The "foxes" and "hounds". The foxes have some psychic ability to cloak themselves and the humans cooperate with the hounds in hunting them. Eventually the foxes strike back attacking the humans.

I believe both the protagonist and author were female.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This makes me think of [*Grass*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?1848) (1989) by Sheri S. Tepper; both the author and the protagonist (Marjorie Westriding) are women.

Quoting the [plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grass_%28novel%29#Plot_summary) on Wikipedia:

> In the distant future Terra (Earth) has become massively over-populated and its resources overstretched. Partially as a result of this, the human race has spread out across the galaxy and populated new worlds. One such world is the eponymous Grass.
>
> The spread of a seemingly incurable plague across human settlements throughout known space prompts the authoritarian religious rulers of humanity, Sanctity, to send investigators to Grass, the only place the plague does not seem to have affected, in the hope of finding a cure.
>
> Given that **the mainly aristocratic inhabitants of Grass have developed an obsession with a localised variant of fox hunting using the planet's native fauna in place of the horses, hounds, and foxes found on Earth**, Sanctity chooses as its investigators the Westriding-Yrarier family, whose equestrian background and upper class roots may enable them to successfully infiltrate the aristocratic society and learn more about the hitherto secretive planet. But the secret of the planet's immunity hides a truth so shattering it could mean the end of life itself.

The Mounts, the Hounds that lead the hunt and the Foxes are all intelligent creatures, to varying degrees.

Comment: That is definitely it. There may be some errors in my recollection of the plot!

Comment: @RoyC Yes, the foxen don't "strike back" - but more detail than that would be spoilers, and I won't spoiler one of my favourite books! :)

Comment: You have inspired me to read this. Enjoying in very much. Thank you.